# Tkinter error messages - redrawing buttons

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, graphics, artificial-intelligence

I write chess on Python3, use Tkinter. I have a problem with bot-mode. Player correctly play: click on buttons and figures move. After player's turn bot should play.

```
def main():
    start_position()
    root.mainloop()
    while king_alive:
        global bot_turn
        if bot_turn:
            cells = l.bot_move(log_field)
            replace(cells[0], cells[1])
            bot_turn = False
```

this is function replace() which change condition of cells on the field

```
def replace(first_cell, second_cell):
    if second_cell.figure.type != 'nofig':
        delete_fig(second_cell.figure)
    first_cell.clicked = False
    second_cell.clicked = False
    second_cell.fig_name = first_cell.fig_name
    second_cell.fig_owner = first_cell.fig_owner
    second_cell.figure = second_cell.get_figure()
    first_cell.figure = l.NoFigure(first_cell.x, first_cell.y, "")
    first_cell.fig_name = ""
    first_cell.fig_owner = ""
    field[second_cell.x][second_cell.y].configure(fg=second_cell.fig_owner, text=second_cell.fig_name)
    field[first_cell.x][first_cell.y].configure(text="")
 demark_cells()
```

people can easily play and move figures, but bot can't do it, however he use the same functions of movement - replace() (input for method replace() are correct. I can't understand the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Даша/Desktop/python/task chess/graphics.py", line 176, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Даша/Desktop/python/task chess/graphics.py", line 171, in main
    replace(cells[0], cells[1])
  File "C:/Users/Даша/Desktop/python/task chess/graphics.py", line 138, in replace
    field[second_cell.x][second_cell.y]['fg'] = second_cell.fig_owner
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1275, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1268, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1259, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
  _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".36689776"
```

how to solve the problem?
P.S. log_field is matrix of every cell conditions
field is matrix of tkinter buttons

Comment: maybe problem in disposition of root.mainloop and code of while (king_alive)... etc

Comment: In tkinter, most of the times that error means you are trying to do something with you destroyed or not created. Maybe  you are destroying an object in delete_fig and try to act on it later in there?

Comment: Also, please read [MCVE]. This code is far from being complete and verifiable.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the line:

```
field[second_cell.x][second_cell.y]['fg'] = second_cell.fig_owner
```

Because you have destroyed, or assigned a different variable to a widget that is called in that line. I don't know exactly what your variables are, but it is probably `field[second_cell.x][second_cell.y]['fg']` or `second_cell`.